# there is an error in your program invalid syntax python 2.7.15

Tags: python, syntax

```
import urllib
import re

symbolslist = ["aapl", "spy", "goog", "nflx"]

i=0
while i<len(symbolslist):
   url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{symbol}?p={symbol}&.tsrc=fin-srch".format(symbol=symbol)
   htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
   htmltext = htmlfile.read()
   regex = '<span id="yfs_184_{symbol}+'">(.+?)</span>'.format(symbol=symbol)"
   pattern = re.compile(regex)
   price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
   print "the price of", symbolslist[i]," is " ,price
   i+1
```

Could someone tell me what's wrong with the above code?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please elaborate your question with more information about your issue? [“Can someone help me?” is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). Please indicate what is the error or problem that you are seeing. Also, are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Use a proper code editor with proper linter mate. Something like pylint or flake8 I am flagging this to be closed as it's _a simple typographical error._

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
regex = '<span id="yfs_184_'+symbolslist[i]'">(.+?)</span>'
```

Needs a `+` after `symbolslist[i]`:

```
regex = '<span id="yfs_184_'+symbolslist[i]+'">(.+?)</span>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `+` symbol:

```
regex = '<span id="yfs_184_'+symbolslist[i]'">(.+?)</span>'
                                          ^
                                          |
here---------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is a great place. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: I did not get any stock price from Yahoo! Finance though.  I guess the web link has changed. How can I update the code to current web link to get the stock prices? Thanks!

Comment: I added the "+" sign, and still could not get the stock prices, here is my current code:    
 
```
import urllib 
import re

symbolslist = ["aaple", "spy", "goog", "nflx"]

for symbol in symbolslist:
   url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s={symbol}&q1=1".format(symbol=symbol)
   htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
   regex = '<span id="yfs_184_{symbol}+'">(.+?)</span>'.format(symbol=symbol)"
   pattern = re.compile(regex)
   price = re.findall(pattern, htmlfile.read())
   print("the price of", symbol," is " ,price)
```

The price placeholders [] are empty in the output. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

use format it make your code more readable https://pyformat.info/

and you missed second `+` in `regex = '<span id="yfs_184_'+symbolslist[i]'">(.+?)</span>'`

```
import urllib
import re

symbolslist = ["aaple", "spy", "goog", "nflx"]

for symbol in symbolslist:
   url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s={symbol}&q1=1".format(symbol=symbol)
   htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
   regex = '<span id="yfs_184_{symbol}">(.+?)</span>'.format(symbol=symbol)
   pattern = re.compile(regex)
   price = re.findall(pattern, htmlfile.read())
   print("the price of", symbol," is " ,price)
```

Comment: I added the "+" sign, and still could not get the stock prices